# Regularity of infinity harmonic functions in $~\mathbb{R}^{2}~$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, holder-spaces

Lets consider the PDE $\Delta_{\infty}f=0$.

The function $f(x,y)=x^{4/3}-y^{4/3}$ is a viscosity solution of that PDE.

It has been shown that viscosity solutions of $\Delta_{\infty}f=0$ in an open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ belongs to $C^{1}(U)$.

In particular, it is said that $f$ belongs to $C^{1,1/3}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$, but I'm not able to demostrate this fact.

Does anyone know how to do that? In every article I read, it's written that it's an "easy matter" to prove it.

But for me it's not!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the definition of $\Delta_\infty f$?

Comment: $\Delta_{\infty} f:=<Df,D^{2}fDf>=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}f_{x_{i}}f_{x_{j}}f_{x_{i}x_{j}}$. But actually I wrote it just to give you an idea why i would like to prove that $f\in C^{1,1/3}$ . I don't think that to know $\Delta_{\infty}$ is  important for the proof.

Comment: Hi @Spiral!  I'm not sure I understand your question.  Do you want to show that any $f$ satisfying $\Delta_\infty f = 0$ is $C^{1,1/3}$, or simply that $f(x,y) = x^{4/3} - y^{4/3}$ is $C^{1,1/3}$?  The former is (I imagine) quite difficult, while the latter is much more elementary.

Comment: Try this reference here https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2004-41-04/S0273-0979-04-01035-3/S0273-0979-04-01035-3.pdf